# Compare a folder of Images to a CSV file in Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Okay so we are setting up a card access system that looks at the Active Directory Users thumbnailPhoto attribute. I am creating an audit system that exports the Users and compares them with the JPG images. If the image exists but there isn't a correlating user, it moves the image into an archive to be reviewed. The goal is to remove old employee photos into a folder incase of later hire. I can't get the image to move into another folder if it matches a name in the CSV. Here is the entire code:

```
<#Write Users to a CSV File #>
$adUsers = get-aduser -filter * -properties displayname | select displayname | export-csv -path PATHWAY.CSV -notypeinformation -encoding unicode
$keepImages = @()
$removeImages = @()

[System.Collections.ArrayList]$arrA = (Get-Childitem -Filter * -path PATHWAY).Basename
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$arrB = Get-Content PATHWAY.CSV

foreach ($itemA in $arrA) {
if ($arrB -ne $itemA) {
$arrB.Remove($itemA)
$removeImages += $itemA }}

$removeImages |out-file -FilePath PATH.csv

<# PUT THE FILES INTO AN ARCHIVE #>
```

--Cant get it to move here, note I am brand new to Powershell, its not like python at all--

Comment: Hey thanks I didnt know that but I clicked it now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this. I have added inline comments to hopefully explain how it works:

```
$ImagesFolder  = 'D:\UserImages'
$OldUserImages = 'D:\UserImages\OldUsers'

# test if the path to move old images exists and if not create it
if (!(Test-Path -Path $OldUserImages -PathType Container)) {
    $null = New-Item -Path $OldUserImages -ItemType Directory
}

# get a list of ADUser display names
$adUsers = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties DisplayName | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DisplayName

# get an array of FileInfo objects of the user images currently in the $ImagesFolder. 
# filter out only those that do not have a basename that correlates to any of the users DisplayName
# and move these to the $OldUserImages folder.

# Tip: if for instance all are of type JPG, add -Filter '*.jpg' to the Get-ChildItem cmdlet.
Get-ChildItem -Path $ImagesFolder -File | 
    Where-Object { $adUsers -notcontains $_.BaseName } | 
    Move-Item -Destination $OldUserImages -Force
```

If you want to keep track of the images you have moved, you can extend the above like:

```
$moved = Get-ChildItem -Path $ImagesFolder -File | 
    Where-Object { $adUsers -notcontains $_.BaseName } | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $file = $_.FullName
        $_ | Move-Item -Destination $OldUserImages -Force
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            'File'    = $file
            'MovedTo' = $OldUserImages
        }
    }

# show result on screen
$moved | Format-Table -AutoSize

# write to CSV file
$out = '{0:yyyy-MM-dd}_MovedImages.csv' -f (Get-Date)
$moved | Export-Csv -Path (Join-Path -Path $ImagesFolder -ChildPath $out) -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: This works 95% but for some reason the file being moved into the CSV file doesnt record into a field in said CSV. Thank you so much for the rest of this though it worked like a charm!

Comment: @TommyCanfield. Ah, sorry.. I forgot to capture the  FullName first. Fixed now.

Comment: You're the best!